# Android MultiTouch only working for one finger

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I am developing a two player Pong game and wish to control the bats, each with one finger. However, my problem is that it only responds to one finger being on the screen at a time. The entire game is ran in one view. First, I check if a pointer is "active" before checking if it occured on the top or bottom of the screen before moving the corresponding bat. It works normally, except for that only one touch registers. My code for the method is below:

```
    // variables
    int _touchY = (int) event.getY();
    boolean isTopSide = true;

    // test if motionEvent was on the top or bottom of the screen
    if (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - _touchY < 0) {
        isTopSide = false;
    }

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            _activePointer = event.getPointerId(0);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(_activePointer != INVALID_POINTER_ID) {
                if (isTopSide) { // top bat
                    _topBat.moveBat(event);
                } else { // bottom bat
                    _botBat.moveBat(event);
                }
            }
            if(_newPointer != INVALID_POINTER_ID){
                if (isTopSide) { // top bat
                    _topBat.moveBat(event);
                } else { // bottom bat
                    _botBat.moveBat(event);
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(_activePointer != INVALID_POINTER_ID){
                _activePointer = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            _activePointer = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if(pointerId == _activePointer){
                _activePointer = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            int newPointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            _newPointer = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            break;
    }
```

Relevant global code

```
// touched
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private int _activePointer = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private int _newPointer = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem why you're only seeing values for a single pointer is because `event.getY()` without any parameter gives you the position for the first pointer index, even if the pointer that actually moved was the second pointer.

The MotionEvent class contains the coordinates for all the active pointers.

If you want to get the second pointer's position, you'll want to call `event.getY(1)`.

You'll probably want to loop through all the active points, getting the total count via `event.getPointerCount()`, and then send the events accordingly.